# Allowing AsyncTask to Manipulate Values in Different Activity Classes

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

This title may seem strange, so let me try to explain what I'm trying to do. I have several activity classes, each representing a different view in my application. My initial activity class gets loaded when the application launches. The user enters values and eventually a TCP socket is opened, and I then use `AsyncTask` to listen for and respond to messages from the server. I'd like for this `AsyncTask` class to essentially listen until the app is closed/error condition reached, and be able to update values in other activity classes after they are started. Does this make sense (it's been a long, frustrating night)? I know that static activity class references are bad practice, and touching the UI thread from other activities is bad as well, but I'm having trouble finding a clean solution to this problem. Maybe using `AsyncTask` is not the best approach here? Should I be using a service instead or something else entirely?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The user enters values and eventually a TCP socket is opened, and I then use AsyncTask to listen for and respond to messages from the server.

`AsyncTask` is designed for short-lived operations (e.g., flash reads, flash writes, Web service calls). Use your own background thread for indefinitely-long operations.

> I'd like for this AsyncTask class to essentially listen until the app is closed/error condition reached

There is no such concept in Android of "app is closed", any more than there is a concept on the Web of "app is closed".

> and be able to update values in other activity classes after they are started.

That sounds like a job for a service, not just some random thread or `AsyncTask`. For starters, once your original activity that started the background thread or `AsyncTask` is destroyed, you gotta gotta gotta get rid of the background thread or `AsyncTask`.

> Should I be using a service instead or something else entirely?

I would strongly recommend you look into services.